# Can multiple cats play on the same object?

Tags: neko-atsume

Can multiple cats stay on a large object, like a Cat Metropolis? Or on any other object of this sort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, multiple cats can play on some larger objects. As you mentioned, the Cat Metropolis is one such item, as can be see in the image below. The [Neko Atsume Wiki](http://nekoatsume.wikia.com/wiki/Cat_Metropolis) page on the Cat Metropolis tells that it can hold up to 6 cats, based on the `Fit` stat.

[image: Cat Metropolis Multi-cat use]

There are some other objects that can also have more than one cat at a time. E.g. the [Cardboard House](http://nekoatsume.wikia.com/wiki/Cardboard_House) at 3. Anything that has a `Fit` statistic greater than one can accommodate more than one cat at a time.